# Valgrind Not Catching Segfaults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm aware that Valgrind keeps track of the memory in a way that allows to to catch segfaults. However, why is not catching the following segfault?

```
int main() {
    char *x = calloc(16, 1);
    char *y = calloc(16, 1);

    x[80] = 'c';
    y[-80] = 'c';

    printf("%c %c\n", *x, *y);
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't it supposed to catch the out of bound access in the heap? According to Valgrind's documentation:

```
But it should detect many errors that could crash your program (eg. cause a segmentation fault).
```

Comment: Is the program actually segment faulting?

Comment: What parameters are you running `valgrind` with?

Comment: Well, it does say "should" and "many", not "will" and "all" :-P

Answer (score 6):

I think you are endowing valgrind with powers rather beyond what it is possible.

It will try to detect various classes of errors and report them to you but it is not possible for it to detect all errors, even in some of the classes of errors it attempts to detect.

In this case what you are dealing with is an out of bounds write to an array which, if valgrind managed to catch it, would be reported as an "invalid write" error. Those are detected by tracking which addresses are "valid" in that they are part of a known heap block.

The problem is that if you index too far past the start or end of an array you may actually wind up with an address that is a valid address in a neighbouring block, which therefore looks absolutely fine to valgrind. To reduce the chance of this happening valgrind adds an area of padding (called a "red zone") each side of a block, but this is only 16 bytes by default.

If you increase the red zone size with the `--redzone-size=128` option then you will find that valgrind does detect the errors in this program.

Comment: Indeed, that explains it. I forgot that Valgrind doesn't see the C semantics. It only sees machine code, so `x[80]` is already an address by the time Valgrind gets to see it. It can't know that you're actually doing `x + 80`.

Comment: I cannot see a `--redzone-size` flag in Valgrind. Furthermore, accessing the array location at N, (so 1 element past the array, since it starts indexing from 0), also is not caught by Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
==24344== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==24344== Copyright (C) 2002-2007, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24344== Using LibVEX rev 1854, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==24344== Copyright (C) 2004-2007, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==24344== Using valgrind-3.3.1-Debian, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==24344== Copyright (C) 2000-2007, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24344== For more details, rerun with: -v
==24344== 
==24344== Invalid write of size 1
==24344==    at 0x8048419: main (testValgrind.c:5)
==24344==  Address 0x418f078 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==24344==    at 0x4021E22: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:397)
==24344==    by 0x804840F: main (testValgrind.c:3)
==24344== 
==24344== Invalid write of size 1
==24344==    at 0x8048422: main (testValgrind.c:6)
==24344==  Address 0x418f018 is 16 bytes before a block of size 16 alloc'd
==24344==    at 0x4021E22: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:397)
==24344==    by 0x80483F8: main (testValgrind.c:2)

==24344== 
==24344== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 1)
==24344== malloc/free: in use at exit: 32 bytes in 2 blocks.
==24344== malloc/free: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 32 bytes allocated.
==24344== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==24344== searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks.
==24344== checked 58,940 bytes.
==24344== 
==24344== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24344==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks.
==24344==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==24344==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==24344==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==24344== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory.
```

Comment: It doesn't here. Weird thing is, it's only index 80 that passes cleanly. For 79 or 81, it detects the error. For 80, it doesn't. Same for -80 vs -79 and -81. Valgrind version 3.8.1.

Comment: It will depend on the layout of the heap, which will depend on things like whether it is a 32 or 64 bit executable and what other blocks the C run time has allocated.